# How to exactly generate hashpassword encoded from python in my flutter app?

Tags: python, flutter, cryptography, pbkdf2

I have a hashed password stored in my database generated from my python api. The hashed password is generated using the `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` package with parameters hmac sha256, phrase encoded to utf8 bytes, salt also in bytes, an iteration of 100000, and a derived key length of 64. The derived key is then concatenated with the salt and encoded as a hexadecimal string which then becomes the users' hashed password. I need the hashed password as basis for the fernet key used to encrypt a file that would be sent to my flutter app. Now, instead of sending the hashed password along with the request to the flutter app, I am trying to replicate the process inside my flutter app. I found this flutter package called `steel_crypt PassCrypt.pbkdf2().hash()` function that has the pbkdf2 hash algorithm which also requires a salt, the phrase, the hmac sha256, derived key length, and iteration. The phrase can be provided by the individual user since it is his/her password. The salt can be acquired by splitting the hashed password from the database. I will be sending the salt to the app in a request because I think it is fairly safe since it's just the salt. I now try to replicate the process but somehow they never match. I think this has got to do with the encoding of the arguments passed to the parameters. Is there anyone who's used the python `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` function I've delved deep into the algorithm to try to find out each argument's runtimetype, or if they matter at all. I've gone on to find out about ascii strings, utf8 encoding, runes, List, raw Strings, and hexadecimals Strings. It's become frustrating. I don't even know if the b'byte' notation of python is a factor also. Isn't `Uint8List` the same as just a `List<int>`?

Here is my python api snippet

```
def pbkdf2_encode(phrase, slen=16, dklen=64):
    try:
        salt = os.urandom(slen)  
        encoded_key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
            'sha256',
            phrase.encode('utf-8'),
            salt,
            100000,
            dklen = dklen,
        ) 
        return (salt + encoded_key).hex()
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise Exception
```

Here is my flutter code snippet

```
    var _hexSalt = '69b4c653613f0e5e2198425dbae704bf'; //<-- received from request
    var _byteSalt = hex.decode(_hexSalt);
    int _iterations = 100000;
    var _passHashByte = PassCryptRaw.pbkdf2(iterations: _iterations, hmac: HmacHash.Sha_256);
    var derived_key = _passHashByte.hash(salt: _byteSalt, len: 64, plain: utf8.encode('admin')); //<-- 'admin' is the phrase
    var _hexHashedPassword = "69b4c653613f0e5e2198425dbae704bf4b42f01a65f706dd26"
        "64ffc9c08e1b84f7899300a2b19082b8e6ebd9579e759b7a249ee03a9033544f4576f24"
        "8f82bfc5d6ef0a36c4c3122b2dd5d4530c4e598"; //<-- just for reference
    var _hexHashedPasswordWithoutSalt = "4bf4b42f01a65f706dd26"
        "64ffc9c08e1b84f7899300a2b19082b8e6ebd9579e759b7a249ee03a9033544f4576f24"
        "8f82bfc5d6ef0a36c4c3122b2dd5d4530c4e598"; //<-- just for reference
   
    print(hex.encode(derived_key));
    print(_hexHashedPasswordWithoutSalt);
    
    // hex.encode(derived_key) should be equal to _hexHashedPasswordWithoutSalt
```

I'm starting to question if this is the right way to do it. I have to point out that the salt and phrase in the flutter function is expecting Uint8List. I suspect these are the parts that are screwing me over. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Or if you could point out how to achieve what I'm asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing other packages and installed these packages called `pbkdf2_dart` and `password_hash`, I didn't know it at the time but these packages have the same Class name and constructor `PBKDF2`. By this time, I've given up on `steel_crypt`. I first tried testing `password_hash`, whose documentation says when not defined, the default hash algorithm is Sha256. All good for me, since I was using Sha256, so I didn't define my hash algorithm in the constructor. Did you know, flutter automatically imports the package you want to to use when you call the class even without you importing the package? Now, I did not read the package name that corresponded to the `PBKDF2` class I imported but I found out later that the one I imported was the `pdkdf2_dart` package, whose default hash algorithm is Sha1. Soooo... Naturally, the generated key did not match my hashed password. I then update my code using `pbkdf2_dart` and unknowingly again thought that the default algorithm was Sha256. Once again, they don't match. I then decide to call the two functions to compare them side by side, it was then that I discovered that they're class names are the same forcing me to give them aliases. At the same time, it made me think did I just switch them while testing? I then took a look at my browser whose current page is the `pbkdf2_dart` constructor page. How did I just find out now that the Hash algorithm I've been using was not the right one. Ultimately, the `pbkdf2_dart` generated the correct hash key after correcting the hash algorithm blunder.

Lesson learned: Carefully make sure that you imported the correct package when you're coding because there might be other packages whose class names and method names be similar or worse yet, are exactly the same.